# Print tokenization of a string

Tags: ocaml, ocamllex

I'm currently working on a programming language as a hobby. It would make lexing errors massively easier to debug if it was possible to have ocamllex print out the tokens it matches as it finds them, I occasionally just add print statements to my rules manually but there should be an easier way to do that.

So what I'm asking is, given a .mll file and some input, is there an automatic way to see the corresponding tokens?

Comment: why are people downvoting this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is a built-in way to ask the lexer to print its tokens.

If you use ocamlyacc, you can set the `p` option in `OCAMLRUNPARAM` to see a trace of the parser's actions. This is described in [Section 12.5](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual026.html) of the OCaml manual. See [Section 10.2](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/manual024.html#ocamlrun-options) for a description of `OCAMLRUNPARAM`.

If you don't mind a crude hack, I just wrote a small script `lext` that adds tracing to the output generated by ocamllex:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
echo '
    let my_engine a b lexbuf =
        let res = Lexing.engine a b lexbuf in
        Printf.printf "Saw token [%s]'\\\\'n" (Lexing.lexeme lexbuf);
        res
'
sed 's/Lexing\.engine/my_engine/g' "$@"
```

It works like this:

```
$ cat ab.mll
rule token = parse
    [' ' '\t'] { token lexbuf }
  | '\n'       { 1 }
  | '+'        { 2 }
  | _          { 3 }
{
    let lexbuf = Lexing.from_channel stdin in
    try
        while true do
            ignore (token lexbuf)
        done
    with _ -> exit 0
}
$ ocamllex ab.mll
5 states, 257 transitions, table size 1058 bytes
$ lext ab.ml > abtraced.ml
$ ocamlopt -o abtraced abtraced.ml
$ echo 'a+b' | abtraced
Saw token []
Saw token [a]
Saw token [+]
Saw token [b]
Saw token [
]
Saw token []
```

Comment: As always, Jeff's answer goes above and beyond expectations.